# Make Clock UWP (C#)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm writing application for windows 10 and need to display Time inside the UI.

I made the display like this

```
 Time.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
```

But I need to update it, any advice on how I can do this?

Comment: There are some good, free courses on UWP development on the MVA web site: https://mva.microsoft.com/

Comment: Really?

I asked for help with time displaying. I know about time picker in UWP.

I need to display time. @FraukeNonnenmacher

Comment: Without knowing what you've tried, it's difficult to help. Can you add your existing code to your question?

Comment: Edited question. I made displaying. How I can update time? @FraukeNonnenmacher

Comment: You need it to update the text of the Time textfield automatically every second? Create a timer, and then, in the timer tick event, write the time into the field. Is it that what youre searching for?

Comment: You need it to update the text of the Time textfield automatically every second

Yes. @Mafii

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this inside your XAML:

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="Time" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
```

and this as your code:

```
public sealed partial class ClockPage : Page
{
    DispatcherTimer Timer = new DispatcherTimer();

    public ClockPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        Timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        Time.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
    }
}
```

Obviously you'll need to change the name of the class to match what you've got, but you get the idea. You may want to tidy things up by using MVVM, this is just a bare-bones example.

Comment: Hey Frauke good answer - keep in minde that greetings and signatures should be ommited in stack overflow to get the focus onto the code, not the person. Ive edited your answer for you.

Comment: Thanks, @Mafii, I wasn't aware of that. Usually somebody else beats me to an answer :)

Comment: Wait should the xaml textblock have to bind to something ?

Comment: @Boommer Generally, yes, you'd have the timer in a view model and use MVVM to bind the XAML to the code instead of using a code-behind file and accessing it by name, but that's somewhat out of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 8):

```
<Window x:Class="StkOverflow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StkOverflow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time, StringFormat='{}{0: h:mm:ss tt}'}"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace StkOverflow
{
public partial class MainWindow
{
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer Timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

    public DateTime Time
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(TimeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TimeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TimeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Time", typeof(DateTime), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Click);
        Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        Timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Time = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Oh - while id say my answer is correct, your answer is cleaner (for mvvm if you put it into the viewmodel)!

Comment: Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Threading' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Error  The member "StringFormat" is not recognized or is not accessible. Milano

Comment: Error CS0229 Ambiguity between 'Menu.Time' and 'Menu.Time'

Comment: Wait - @FrancescaAldrovandi is that a wpf solution or did you actually test this in uwp?

Comment: This is Universal App for windows 10

Comment: this is a wpf solution, you should use this Windows.UI.Xaml namespace for the DispatcherTimer

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add a [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) to your class:

```
private Timer timer;
```

Create a handler for the `Elapsed` event of the timer:

```
private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Time.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
}
```

And then in the constructor of your window, you can add this:

```
timer = new Timer(1000); // let the timer tick every 1000 ms = every second
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
timer.Enabled = true; // Enable it
```

Comment: Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'ElapsedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Error CS1729 'Timer' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: Error CS1061 'Timer' does not contain a definition for 'Elapsed' and no extension method 'Elapsed' accepting a first argument of type 'Timer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'ElapsedEventHandler' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Milano

Comment: @ЕвгенийСухомлин im sorry - apparently you dont have the same dlls that I do. Glad you found another solution!