# C# : How to display a clock on multiple pages in Windows core IOT app

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windowsiot

I'm new to UWP and I'm trying to display a clock on a Windows core IOT app on multiple pages. What would be the best way to do this?

I tried to use a class for the time and to update it dynamically and bind it with the header, but how would I bind a header that is from a "template"? The header I want to put the clock in is in a `ResourceDictionary` that I use on all pages of the app. Or should I put the clock in `App.xaml`, but even in this case, how can I bind it to the header so that it will always be updated?

Do I need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in my class and or is there another way?

Thank you.

***EDIT:*** (05/17)

This is the code for the header

**ResourceDictionnary:**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns:local="using:Project.Resources"
 x:Class="Project.Header">
<!-- ... -->
   <!-- Header -->
   <DataTemplate x:Key="Header" x:DataType="local:Header">
      <TextBlock x:Name="labelHeader" Text="{x:Bind Time, Mode=OneWay}"/>
   </DataTemplate>
<!-- ... -->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: You can update the time using a timer [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38562704/make-clock-uwp-c). And about the header, it is best to show your code here.

Comment: @Rita Han - MSFT Thank you for commenting. I don't have a problem updating the clock for one page, what I'm trying to do is to bind the same code of the clock to multiple pages. If I bind it to only one page, it works. How would I be able to "share" the same behind code with multiple pages, or how should I update in general something like this (something that is shared between multiple pages, but changes dynamically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put the clock to every page. You can use `Frame` control to host other pages as content of the `MainPage`. Put the clock on the MainPgae "header". Navigation between other pages occurs outside of the clock region. Then you can only update the clock in MainPage and share it between other pages.

The following is a simple sample you can reference:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" Margin="20,5,5,5"/>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Name="Page1" Content="Page1" Click="Page1_Click" />
        <Button Name="Page2" Content="Page2" Click="Page2_Click" />
        <Button Name="Page3" Content="Page3" Click="Page3_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Frame Name="MyFrame"></Frame>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
    Clock clock = new Clock();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = clock;
        clock.InitClock();
    }

    private void Page1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page1));
    }

    private void Page2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
    }

    private void Page3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page3));
    }
```

**Clock.cs**

```
public class Clock : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    DispatcherTimer Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    public string _time { get; set; }
    public string Time
    {
        get { return _time; }
        set
        {
            _time = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Time");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler hander = PropertyChanged;
        if (hander != null)
        {
            hander(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

    }

    public void InitClock()
    {
        Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        Timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example!

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go out on a limb here, and suggest that instead of adding identical elements to every page in your application, you should use two frames.

The outpost frame is used for elements that are present on every page. That can be your header, menus, updating time -you name it. Makes dealing with that content easier.

Withing it place a second frame, and use that for navigation between pages. Take a look at our app - it's has a vertical "header" marked 'Page 1', and the right side has 'Page 2' - that the one used for navigation.

[image: Two frames]

Comment: Thank you, I understand that this would simplify things a lot, I'll try to do that after I finish all the other things I need to implement in the app.. Meanwhile if someone gives an answer that is closer to what I already have I'll try those methods first.

Comment: Thank you I tried it and it's easier, I'm going to mark @Rita Han - MSFT 's answer as the solution because of the example. Thanks a lot